# Is there any way I can guard this pipe from screws and nails?

Tags: plumbing, screws, nails

I tried to take down a shelf yesterday and water started coming from the wall. Called a plumber and discovered this in my building's water main:

[image: Screw in building water pipe]

The pipe is big enough and close enough to the drywall that it probably looks just like a stud to a stud finder or similar.

Is there any way I can install some kind of nail guard in front of the pipe or otherwise standard way I can indicate to the next guy to not drill in this location?

Comment: LOL, too bad it wasn't an electrical cable or the problem might have been "self-correcting". What you need to do is tear down all the walls in the house and install 1/4" hardened armor plate in front of all the water and electrical pipes.

Answer (score 1):

That screw seems to have found the magic spot and I think it's unlikely to happen again, however you might want to somehow strap a [protection plate](https://www.google.com/search?q=electrical+protection+plate&biw=1280&bih=890&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=wcWUVY38J8i_ggSNmZD4BA&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAg#tbm=isch&q=nail+protection+plate) around the Tee; I wouldn't worry about the rest of the pipe.

Comment: There's a protection plate already every place the pipe goes through the stud.

Comment: @BillyONeal By "the rest of the pipe", I meant the vertical run. AFAIK, there's no standard practice for protecting that. Good that it is otherwise, as it's required on stud penetrations.